# Javascript does not return servlet response

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have wriiten welcome screen which basically use below javascript to call creditCheck servlet.  Within servlet, there is method which will check the username and password. Servlet returns value properly. alert is not getting generated after servlet excutation within javascript.

however if execute simple servlet ( not doing anything, just printing variables), it will generate alert.

below is my javascript within JSp file:

```
############################################

<script type="text/javascript">

                    function getXmlHttpRequestObject(){
                        var xmlHttp = false;
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                            return new XMLHttpRequest(); //To support the browsers IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        }
                        else if(window.ActiveXObject){
                            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For the browsers IE6, IE5 
                        }
                        else    {
                        alert("Error due to old verion of browser upgrade your browser");
                        }
                    }



            var xmlhttp = new getXmlHttpRequestObject(); //xmlhttp holds the ajax object
            function servletPost() {
                if(xmlhttp) { 
                var username = document.getElementById("uname");
                var password = document.getElementById("pass");
                xmlhttp.open("POST","CredCheck",true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServletPost;
                req.onreadystatechange = callback;

                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xmlhttp.send("uname=" + username.value + "&pass=" + password.value );

                }
            }

            function handleServletPost() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);  
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Ajax calling error");
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
```

#

Comment: Where is your callback function? In general, there are JS libraries that handle all the AJAX for you so you don't usually write your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed xmlhttp.open("POST","CredCheck",true);   to

xmlhttp.open("POST","CredCheck",false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServletPost;